# Mojolicious can't find my controller

Tags: mojolicious

I'm trying to get the project hosted on [github](https://github.com/nickandrew/LS30/tree/master/lib/LS30) running.

From the root directory I'm running

> /LS30$ morbo bin/webserver

which starts the server. Navigating to http://ip:port/settings I get the following error

```
[Fri Jan 15 15:27:20 2016] [debug] Controller "LS30::Web::Settings" does not exist.
```

Now the controller is located here: LS30::Web::Controller::Settings so it is looking in the wrong place.

Since it is looking in the wrong place I figured why not copy the Settings controller (and the base controller) where it was looking - but this just gives me this error instead:

```
[Fri Jan 15 15:31:45 2016] [debug] Class "LS30::Web::Settings" is not a controller.
```

The [routes](https://github.com/nickandrew/LS30/blob/master/lib/LS30/Web.pm) look correct to a beginner, so I don't think it's that. In fact I suspect it's probably something wrong in my environment since I know this worked for the original author.

I'm very new to this so I'm not really sure what to do next:/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mojolicious version 5.25 adds "Controller" automatically to a class name in an app when it's searching for a class to use to execute a route.

In this case, the app is `LS30::Web` and it's looking for a class called `Settings`. Mojolicious 5.25 and later test the classes `LS30::Web::Controller::Settings` and `LS30::Web::Settings` but earlier versions test only the latter, which doesn't exist.

The solution therefore, is to upgrade your Mojolicious to 5.25 or later. If you are using Ubuntu, upgrade to `vivid` or later. Otherwise, use CPAN or a tool such as `cpanm` to download and install the most recent Mojolicious from source.